# Configuring the Analyzers (LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Synonym) for Azure search in Sitecore 8.2.1

Tags: azure-search

I had used Lucene and sometimes SOLR for Older Sitecore versions. Now the latest trend seems to be Azure search with Sitecore 8.2.1.
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/configure_azure_search#_Create_a_Search

Did anyone get a chance to explore with Azure Search in Sitecore? Any approaches for configuring Analyzers (LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Synonym)??

I' using Azure search in Sitecore 8.2.1 web app, assuming replace configurations of Lucene with Azurecloudsearch?. Any suggestions, please.

Comment: Looking for similar configuration how we have in [Lucene and Solr](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/036144)